# Juntar 2 selects em um só, mostrando os campos

Tags: sql, oracle

O 1º select mostra os seguintes campos:

```
CONCAT - FILIAL - COD. PRODUTO - DESCRICAO - QNTD. VENDAS PUB.
  11   -   1    -       1      - PRODUTO 1 -        10
  12   -   1    -       2      - PRODUTO 2 -        20
  13   -   1    -       3      - PRODUTO 3 -        30
```

O 2º select mostra os seguintes campos:

```
CONCAT - FILIAL - COD. PRODUTO - DESCRICAO - QNTD. VENDAS PRIV.
  11   -   1    -       1      - PRODUTO 1 -        11
  12   -   1    -       2      - PRODUTO 2 -        22
  13   -   1    -       3      - PRODUTO 3 -        33
  19   -   1    -       9      - PRODUTO 9 -        99
```

Preciso de juntar esses 2 selects onde possa mostrar o resultado da seguinte forma:

```
CONCAT - FILIAL - COD. PRODUTO - DESCRICAO - QNTD. VENDAS PUB. - QNTD. VENDAS PRIV.
  11   -   1    -       1      - PRODUTO 1 -        10          -        11
  12   -   1    -       2      - PRODUTO 2 -        20          -        22
  13   -   1    -       3      - PRODUTO 3 -        30          -        33
  19   -   1    -       9      - PRODUTO 9 -         0          -        99
```

Utilizando union não me atende, pois as somas do campo QNTD. VENDAS PRIV. ficariam no mesmo campo do publ.

---

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(PCPEDC.CODFILIAL, PCPEDI.CODPROD) AS CONCAT,
  PCPEDC.CODFILIAL AS FILIAL,
  PCPEDI.CODPROD AS "COD. PRODUTO",
  PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO AS DESCRICAO,
  Sum(PCPEDI.QT) AS "QNTD. VENDAS PUB."
FROM
  PCPEDI,
  PCCLIENT,
  PCPEDC,
  PCATIVI,
  PCPRODUT
WHERE
  PCPEDI.CODPROD = PCPRODUT.CODPROD
  AND PCPEDI.CODCLI = PCCLIENT.CODCLI
  AND PCPEDI.NUMPED = PCPEDC.NUMPED
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 = PCATIVI.CODATIV
  AND PCPEDI.POSICAO = 'F'
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 IN (60, 52, 51, 43, 44, 49)
  AND PCPEDC.CODFILIAL IN (1)
  AND PCPEDC.CONDVENDA = 1
GROUP BY
  PCPEDI.CODPROD,
  PCPEDC.CODFILIAL
ORDER BY
  "COD. PRODUTO"


SELECT
  CONCAT(PCPEDC.CODFILIAL, PCPEDI.CODPROD) AS CONCAT,
  PCPEDC.CODFILIAL AS FILIAL,
  PCPEDI.CODPROD AS "COD. PRODUTO",
  PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO AS DESCRICAO,
  Sum(PCPEDI.QT) AS "QNTD. VENDAS PRIV."
FROM
  PCPEDI,
  PCCLIENT,
  PCPEDC,
  PCATIVI,
  PCPRODUT
WHERE
  PCPEDI.CODPROD = PCPRODUT.CODPROD
  AND PCPEDI.CODCLI = PCCLIENT.CODCLI
  AND PCPEDI.NUMPED = PCPEDC.NUMPED
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 = PCATIVI.CODATIV
  AND PCPEDI.POSICAO = 'F'
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 NOT IN (60, 52, 51, 43, 44, 49, 62, 64, 2, 99, 1)
  AND PCPEDC.CODFILIAL IN (1)
  AND PCPEDC.CONDVENDA = 1
GROUP BY
  PCPEDI.CODPROD,
  PCPEDC.CODFILIAL
ORDER BY
  "COD. PRODUTO"
```

**Pré solução do Developer:**

```
SELECT VENDAS_PUBLICAS.CONCAT,
       --demais colunas
       VENDAS_PUBLICAS.QNTD_VENDAS_PUB, 
       VENDAS_PRIVADAS.QNTD_VENDAS_PRIV 
FROM 
(SELECT
  CONCAT(PCPEDC.CODFILIAL, PCPEDI.CODPROD) AS CONCAT,
  PCPEDC.CODFILIAL AS FILIAL,
  PCPEDI.CODPROD AS "COD. PRODUTO",
  PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO AS DESCRICAO,
  Sum(PCPEDI.QT) AS "QNTD_VENDAS_PUB"
FROM PCPEDI, PCCLIENT, PCPEDC, PCATIVI, PCPRODUT
WHERE PCPEDI.CODPROD = PCPRODUT.CODPROD
  AND PCPEDI.CODCLI = PCCLIENT.CODCLI
  AND PCPEDI.NUMPED = PCPEDC.NUMPED
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 = PCATIVI.CODATIV
  AND PCPEDI.POSICAO = 'F'
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 IN (60, 52, 51, 43, 44, 49)
  AND PCPEDC.CODFILIAL IN (1)
  AND PCPEDC.CONDVENDA = 1
GROUP BY PCPEDI.CODPROD, PCPEDC.CODFILIAL 
ORDER BY "COD. PRODUTO") as VENDAS_PUBLICAS,
(SELECT CONCAT(PCPEDC.CODFILIAL, PCPEDI.CODPROD) AS CONCAT, 
       PCPEDC.CODFILIAL AS FILIAL,
       PCPEDI.CODPROD AS "COD. PRODUTO", 
       PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO AS DESCRICAO, 
       Sum(PCPEDI.QT) AS "QNTD_VENDAS_PRIV"
FROM PCPEDI, PCCLIENT, PCPEDC, PCATIVI, PCPRODUT 
WHERE PCPEDI.CODPROD = PCPRODUT.CODPROD
  AND PCPEDI.CODCLI = PCCLIENT.CODCLI
  AND PCPEDI.NUMPED = PCPEDC.NUMPED
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 = PCATIVI.CODATIV
  AND PCPEDI.POSICAO = 'F'
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 NOT IN (60, 52, 51, 43, 44, 49, 62, 64, 2, 99, 1)
  AND PCPEDC.CODFILIAL IN (1)
  AND PCPEDC.CONDVENDA = 1
GROUP BY PCPEDI.CODPROD, PCPEDC.CODFILIAL
ORDER BY "COD. PRODUTO") as VENDAS_PRIVADAS
WHERE VENDAS_PUBLICAS.CONCAT = VENDAS_PRIVADAS.CONCAT
```

Comment: O que realmente quer com isso? já tentou usar o `union` ou o `union all`?

Comment: Já tentei sim. Só que as 2 somas ficam na mesma coluna. O que preciso é de 2 colunas das somas

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa tenta melhorar ela concerteza vai aparecer muito gente pra ajudar.

Comment: Marconi, fiz edição na descrição com exemplos. Veja se consegue me ajudar ou outra pessoa.

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Se vc criar os campos QTDE VENDAS PUB e QTDE VENDAS PRIV para os dois selects não pode ajudar? Uma coluna vai ficar vazia em um dos dois select's

Comment: Hum, entendi. Vou tentar aqui e retorno.

Comment: @Adalberto deu certo?

Answer (score 1):

Faça um outer join usando os selects como tabelas virtuais

```
select *
from (select ... concat ... ) s1,
     (select ... concat ... ) s2
where s1.concat (+) = s2.concat
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue a alteração da sua query com a solução do Motta:

```
SELECT VENDAS_PUBLICAS.CONCAT,
       --demais colunas
       VENDAS_PUBLICAS.[QNTD. VENDAS PUB.], 
       VENDAS_PRIVADAS.[QNTD. VENDAS PRIV.] 
FROM 
(SELECT
  CONCAT(PCPEDC.CODFILIAL, PCPEDI.CODPROD) AS CONCAT,
  PCPEDC.CODFILIAL AS FILIAL,
  PCPEDI.CODPROD AS "COD. PRODUTO",
  PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO AS DESCRICAO,
  Sum(PCPEDI.QT) AS "QNTD. VENDAS PUB."
FROM PCPEDI, PCCLIENT, PCPEDC, PCATIVI, PCPRODUT
WHERE PCPEDI.CODPROD = PCPRODUT.CODPROD
  AND PCPEDI.CODCLI = PCCLIENT.CODCLI
  AND PCPEDI.NUMPED = PCPEDC.NUMPED
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 = PCATIVI.CODATIV
  AND PCPEDI.POSICAO = 'F'
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 IN (60, 52, 51, 43, 44, 49)
  AND PCPEDC.CODFILIAL IN (1)
  AND PCPEDC.CONDVENDA = 1
GROUP BY PCPEDI.CODPROD, PCPEDC.CODFILIAL 
ORDER BY "COD. PRODUTO") as VENDAS_PUBLICAS,
(SELECT CONCAT(PCPEDC.CODFILIAL, PCPEDI.CODPROD) AS CONCAT, 
       PCPEDC.CODFILIAL AS FILIAL,
       PCPEDI.CODPROD AS "COD. PRODUTO", 
       PCPRODUT.DESCRICAO AS DESCRICAO, 
       Sum(PCPEDI.QT) AS "QNTD. VENDAS PRIV."
FROM PCPEDI, PCCLIENT, PCPEDC, PCATIVI, PCPRODUT 
WHERE PCPEDI.CODPROD = PCPRODUT.CODPROD
  AND PCPEDI.CODCLI = PCCLIENT.CODCLI
  AND PCPEDI.NUMPED = PCPEDC.NUMPED
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 = PCATIVI.CODATIV
  AND PCPEDI.POSICAO = 'F'
  AND PCCLIENT.CODATV1 NOT IN (60, 52, 51, 43, 44, 49, 62, 64, 2, 99, 1)
  AND PCPEDC.CODFILIAL IN (1)
  AND PCPEDC.CONDVENDA = 1
GROUP BY PCPEDI.CODPROD, PCPEDC.CODFILIAL
ORDER BY "COD. PRODUTO") as VENDAS_PRIVADAS
WHERE VENDAS_PUBLICAS.CONCAT = VENDAS_PRIVADAS.CONCAT
```

No meu entendimento, as colunas codfilial e codprod identificam cada linha, então essa solução vai funcionar.

A solução consiste em transformar as suas consultas em tabelas para poder fazer um join.

Comment: Erro ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Cause: A column name was specified improperly in the current SQL statement. 

Action: Check the statement's syntax, especially references to column names, and retry the statement.

Comment: Não está reconhecendo essa coluna: VENDAS_PUBLICAS.[QNTD. VENDAS PUB.]

Esqueci de mencionar acima, que o banco é oracle.

Comment: Substitui os espaços por "_", QNTD. VENDAS PUB. para QNTD_VENDAS_PUB e remove os pontos e "[", "]".  Ficaria assim :VENDAS_PUBLICAS.QNTD_VENDAS_PUB

Comment: Outro erro agora: ORA-00933
SQL command not properly ended

Cause: The SQL statement ends with an inappropriate clause. For example, an ORDER BY clause may have been included in a CREATE VIEW or INSERT statement. ORDER BY cannot be used to create an ordered view or to insert in a certain order.

Comment: Action: Correct the syntax by removing the inappropriate clauses. It may be possible to duplicate the removed clause with another SQL statement. For example, to order the rows of a view, do so when querying the view and not when creating it. This error can also occur in SQL*Forms applications if a continuation line is indented. Check for indented lines and delete these spaces.

Comment: Pode me enviar a sua query?

Comment: Editei na descrição.

Comment: consegui ver Developer?

Comment: Você consegue criar essa estrutura no sqlfiddle.com?  Estou tentando solucionar outra questão postada aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127503/listar-registros-que-est%C3%A3o-em-uma-tabela-e-os-que-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A3o-na-mesma-tabela/127609#127609, esse sql ajudou bastante.  Não precisa criar com todos os campos, só minimo necessário com alguns registros, vai ficar mais fácil para te ajudar.