# Listar registros que estão em uma tabela e os que não estão na mesma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela pontos e uma tabela users. Em pontos, tenho um ID que referencia o usuário da tabela users. O que preciso fazer é retornar todos os usuário que bateram o ponto, juntamente com os que não bateram o ponto. Assim, consigo ver quem bateu e quem não bateu ponto em qualquer data.

A tabela pontos tem os seguintes dados:

- **data** tipo Date (data que o usuário bateu o ponto)
- **usuarioId** (referencia do id do usuário na tabela User)
- **entrada01** tipo TIME (horário que o usuário entrou)
- **saida01** tipo TIME (horário que o usuário saiu)
- **entrada02** tipo TIME (horário que o usuário entrou)
- **saida02** tipo TIME (horário que o usuário saiu)

A tabela user tem os seguintes dados:
id, nome

Comment: Algo assim não resolve? `select * from users inner join pontos on pontos.user = user.id`

Comment: @DiegoF Desse jeito eu só consigo ver quem bateu, porém eu preciso retornar, também, quem não bateu o ponto em cada data.

Comment: Então mostre a estrutura da sua tabela, na pergunta não está claro.

Comment: Alterei o código para mostrar os atributos.

Comment: Se é pra mostrar todos os usuários, um `users LEFT JOIN pontos` deve resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Vou assumir que um utilizador que tenha entrada01 ou entrada02 na data selecionada tenha picado o ponto.

```
DECLARE @DATA DATE;
SET @DATA = '2016-05-09';



select
    nome,
    CASE WHEN Picou > 0 then 'Sim' else 'Não' end 'Picou'
from (
    select
        u.nome,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(d.entrada01) = @DATA OR
        DATE(d.entrada02) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Picou'
    from user u
    left join dados d on
        u.id = d.usuarioid
    group by
        u.nome
) t
```

EDIT:

```
DECLARE @DATA DATE;
SET @DATA = '2016-05-09';

select
    u.nome,
    d.*
from user u
left join (
    select
        d.*
    from dados d on
    where
        DATE(d.entrada01) = @DATA OR
        DATE(d.entrada02) = @DATA
) d on
    u.id = d.usuarioid
```

Comment: funcionou. Porém, eu preciso retornar todos os atributos que coloquei (dataPonto, u.nome, entrada01, saida01, entrada02, saida02) pois, a princípio, tenho que retornar todas as datas. Modifiquei a sua solução para retornar esses atributos e o meu retorno foi assim:
dos 5 usuários que tenho no meu banco, apenas um bateu o ponto na data especificada por você. Os outros 4 apareceram com os atributos preenchidos por valores de outras tuplas. Por exemplo, um usuário apareceu com a data de um dia em que ele bateu o ponto. Não sei se deu pra entender.

Comment: Podias verificar se o EDIT é o que estas a tentar? Caso contrário sugiro que incluas dados de exemplo e o resultado esperado.

Comment: ainda não é o que eu espero. Vamos tentar conforme você sugeriu. Suponha que eu tenha 5 usuários na minha tabela User. No entanto, apenas 2 usuários registraram o seu ponto. Logo, na data "09-05-2016" vai ter apenas duas usuários registrados. O meu objetivo é listar todos os pontos, mas vamos filtrar só pela data "09-05-2016". Então, ao selecionar essa data, eu quero ver os usuários que bateram o ponto (no caso apenas 2) mais os outros 3 que não bateram. Assim, eu saberei quem bateu o ponto e quem deixou de bater. Deu pra entender mais ou menos?

Comment: A query abaixo do "EDIT" tem que retornar isso. Todos os users e os users que tiverem picado o ponto vão ter dados associados, os outros não.

Answer (score 1):

Na solução do Caffé, só faltou incluir uma cláusula no where data is null:

```
    select 
    user.id, user.nome, ponto.data, ponto.entrada01, 
    ponto.saida01, ponto.entrada02, ponto.saida02
    (case when ponto.data is not null then 'sim' else 'não') as bateu_ponto
from user left join ponto on ponto.usuarioId = user.id
where (data is null or (data between data1 and data2))
group by user.id, user.nome, ponto.data, ponto.entrada01, 
ponto.saida01, ponto.entrada02, ponto.saida02, bateu_ponto
```

Os usuários que não bateram o ponto não possuem a data, por este motivo, você precisa também considerar que a data seja nula ou no intervalo que você informar para os usuários que possuem ponto.

======================SOLUÇÃO CORRETA=====================

A solução acima não atende. Se o usuário tiver ponto em data diferente da informada no where, ou seja, não atende as cláusulas do where pois não é nula e é diferente da data do filtro.

A solução correta foi criar uma sub query somente com os pontos do dia que você deseja consultar, com essa tabela fiz um left join com user, agora todos os usuarios estão sendo retornados mesmo que existam pontos para outras datas.  Segue a nova query:

```
select user.id, user.name, ponto.dataPonto, 
       ponto.entrada01, ponto.saida01, 
       ponto.entrada02, ponto.saida02,
    case when (ponto.dataPonto is not null) then 'sim' else 'não' end as bateu_ponto

from user left join

     (select * 

      from pontospordia p 

      where p.dataPonto between '2016-05-07' and '2016-05-10 23:59:59') ponto on ponto.usuarioId = user.id
group by user.id, 
         user.name, 
         ponto.dataPonto, 
         ponto.entrada01, 
         ponto.saida01, 
         ponto.entrada02, 
         ponto.saida02
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: @Caffé, eu fiz um teste excluindo o último insert da tabela pontospordia, já que estava igual ao penúltimo. Nesse caso, apenas um usuário teria batido o ponto na data '2016-05-10'. Assim, ele deveria retornar 4 usuários null, correto? Vejam: [link]http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdcdf5/2

Comment: @Caffé Marcelo, acho que já entendi o que você quer com base no seu último comentário.  Uma vez informado um período, você quer que para cada dia desse período todos os usuários sejam exibidos, nesse caso, teríamos que pensar numa terceira solução.  É isso?

Comment: Isso, @Caffé. Exatamente isso. Quero ver todos os usuários para cada dia.

Comment: Algum problema em ter que criar uma procedure?

Comment: O problema é que quando um funcionário bate o ponto em uma data, ele não aparece como faltoso na outra data em que não bateu.

Answer (score 0):

Isso funciona:

```
select 
    user.id, user.name, ponto.dataPonto, ponto.entrada01, 
    ponto.saida01, ponto.entrada02, ponto.saida02,
    case when ponto.dataPonto is not null then 'sim' else 'não' end bateu_ponto
from 
    user left join pontospordia ponto on ponto.usuarioId = user.id
where 
    (dataPonto between '2016-05-07' and '2016-05-10')
    or dataPonto is null
group by 
    user.id, user.name, ponto.dataPonto, ponto.entrada01, 
    ponto.saida01, ponto.entrada02, ponto.saida02, bateu_ponto
```

Acima está a minha query original acrescida do *OR* do @Developer.

Veja funcionando no seu sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/332356/60.

A única coisa é que pesquisar por mais de uma data e mostrar a data da query não ajuda muito a saber **quando** um usuário não bateu ponto, pois se ele não bateu ele não terá um registro correspondente na tabela de batidas, de modo que não vai mostrar a data pra ele.

A solução é consultar por uma única data e exibir no aplicativo a data usada para a consulta em vez de tentar obter esta data a partir do resultado da query.

Comment: testei a sua solução aqui, mas só mostra os usuários que bateram o ponto. Os usuários que não bateram não aparecem.

Comment: O left join faz com que todos usuarios sejam retornados, mesmo que não exista ponto.  A query não me parece estar errada.  Substitui o where por data is null or (data between data1 and data2) .  O problema está nas linhas que não possuem data, você precisa incluir o data is null.

Comment: @Developer, Fiz conforme você falou, só troquei o data between... por uma data fixa. Mas dos 5 usuários que eu tenho, só 3 foram retornados

Comment: @MarceloAugusto Editei a resposta com a minha query definitiva.